# Issue with Flutter Material 3 looking like 120% zoom

Tags: flutter, flutter-material

I have a strange issue with Material 3 theme in flutter.
For some reason, when I enable the material3 flag, every button and text enlarges way over how it would normally need to look on the device.
I have generated my color scheme using the [material 3 theme builder](https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom)

My theme data is as minimal as possible:

```
ThemeData(
visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
useMaterial3: true,
colorScheme: darkColorScheme,
```

)

This is how it looks when I toggle the material3 flag to `false`
[image]

And this is how it looks like when I toggle the material 3 theme:
[image]

For some reason the material 3 theme take a lot more space on my device and I have the code from the oficial material 3 example that is [showcased here](https://flutter.github.io/samples/web/material_3_demo/#/)

As you can see that code looks a lot better and without such big padding as I get on my device.
Is that a configuration somewhere or why am I having this big differences in look and feel?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the expected behaviour.
[Material API Doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/useMaterial3.html) says

*...A temporary flag used to opt-in to Material 3 features.
If true, then widgets that have been migrated to Material 3 will use new colors, typography and other features of Material 3. If false, they will use the Material 2 look and feel....*

**Edit:**

Also from [Material Doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/material)
*...You can opt in to Material 3 using the useMaterial3 flag. However, your UI might be inconsistent until all of Flutter and your code are migrated....*

I am not 100% sure, but above reasons are very likely the cause of your issue. We can fully be sure, once flutter migrates to material 3 as default.

Comment: But there is a discrepancy with my material 3 look and the one from their showcase. Mine look a lot bigger then in their own example app.